# Hystrix does not throw HystrixRuntimeException, and instead empty message error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

I use Hystrix (version Camden.SR7 of `spring-cloud-dependencies`) in spring-boot app on service layer without fallback methods. One of service's method looks like the following:

```
@HystrixCommand(commandKey = "prefs",
        commandProperties = { @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "2000")})
@Override
public void savePrefs(PrefsRequestParams requestParams) throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

If such method executes longer than 2 seconds, Hystrix will throw java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null, and REST response will look like:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1509452672714,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/prefs"
}
```

With such response it's unclear from which method exception actually was thrown. If I change `spring-cloud-dependencies` version to Brixton.SR5 (previous version), it returns clear response:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1509452426819,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException",
    "message": "prefs timed-out and fallback failed.",
    "path": "/prefs"
}
```

**So new version of Hystrix (actually new version of  spring-cloud-dependencies) does not throw HystrixRuntimeException. Is it a bug or should I configure Hystrix in another way to receive clear message error?**

I use the following maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Camden.SR7</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
     ...
```

from maven dependency tree I see that it uses `com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.5.6:compile` for `spring-cloud-dependencies` version Camden.SR7,
and for version Brixton.SR5 - `com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.5.3:compile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating to Javanica 1.5.12 resolves the issue.

From 1.5.7 there is also an option to force throwing HystrixRuntimeException for all not ignored exceptions:

```
@HystrixCommand(raiseHystrixExceptions = {HystrixException.RUNTIME_EXCEPTION})
@Override
public void savePrefs(PrefsRequestParams requestParams) throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

Comment: which version of hystrix-javanica should I use? I don't see such option for hystrix-javanica-1.5.6

Comment: Ah right, should ask about a version first. It's there in latest 1.5.12 version, not sure when it was included.

Comment: It's included from version 1.5.7.

Comment: thank you, it works fine after upgrading to version 1.5.12. app even works without raiseHystrixExceptions option. I guess it was a bug in hystrix-javanica version 1.5.6.    
please update / add to your answer that it's needed to use 1.5.12 version, and I will accept it :)

Comment: Thx but i do not want to take credit for this ;>. I would rather delete my answer and You can provide your own or just update the question.

Comment: your answer and comments led to solution, so why not to update answer in a such case

Comment: You convinced me ;>